# Is there a difference in effeciency between applying a function to a single element or a collection in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Say you have the option to either apply a function to an individual DOM element or a list of them:

Individual:

```
$('#element1').click(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
    return false; 
});
$('#element2').click(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
    return false; 
});
$('#element3').click(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
    return false; 
});
```

Vs a collection:

```
 $('#element1, #element2, #element3').click(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
    return false; 
});
```

Aside from writing less code, is there any computational benefit of applying functions to collections? Will the code run any faster?

The reason I am asking is because my elements are JS objects and I need to process them individually.

Comment: Well the former applies a clickhandler to one element while the latter does the work to three elements. So I assume the first example you mean to compare to is calling `$(".element").click(...);  $(".button").click(...); $(".form").click(...)` each separately?

Comment: I don't think you can compare as such. The first is just 1 element 1 handler vs 3 elements and 3 handlers. Perhaps you can improvise by creating a external function (`function blahblah(} { }`) and pass the reference to the jQuery.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practical terms, no, there's no appreciable difference. If you get very micro-optimisation-minded, then binding them individually runs in about 65% of the time that the multiple selector does, but, seriously, just use the multiple selector - it's more readable and much more maintainable.

Source: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-problems

Comment: +1 For a pointer to http://jsperf.com/ Every web developer should learn and use this site to test these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any performance improvement by using the second method, if there are any that will be very negligible.

But if you are looking at memory conception second method might be good since there is only one inner function created and same reference is used by all three elements.

Comment: Are you sure about it? I don't think it uses any kind of references even when you group selectors.

Comment: What I meant is the callback function references, First method create 3 inner functions while second one creates 1.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just applying the code on a class and add this class to your 3 elements :)

```
$('.hide').click(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
    return false; 
});
```

If you want the same behavior for different elements, I think it is a better to add class to elements than registering the click event for each of your elements.

and you will have this html

```
<a href="#" id="element1" class="hide"></a>
<a href="#" id="element2" class="hide"></a>
<a href="#" id="element3" class="hide"></a>
```

Comment: The OP wasn't asking for an alternative way of accomplishing this effect, rather he was asking about the performance differences between the two.